# Spring Boot + Logback: placeholders can be resolved locally but not in Openshift

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openshift, logback

Suppose you have this kind of `logback-spring.xml` with placeholders (just a sample):

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <springProperty name="appName" source="spring.application.name" scope="context"/>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
          <encoder>
             <pattern>${appName}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This works perfectly if you have this file in `resources` or pass it via `logging.level` property.

But when I try to bind this file in Openshift via configmap, this error happens:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'appName' in value "<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <springProperty name="appName" source="spring.application.name" scope="context"/>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
          <encoder>
             <pattern>${appName}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:230)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:88)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:535)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at ******
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

Configmap in Openshift looks like this:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  ******
data:
  logback-spring.xml: |
    <configuration>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
        <springProperty name="appName" source="spring.application.name" scope="context"/>
        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
              <encoder>
                 <pattern>${appName}</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>
    </configuration>
```

I bind that config in the "Environment" section of the deployment config in this way:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work with volumes. Here is the part of the deployment config:

```
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: logback-configmap-volume
      configMap:
        name: logback-configmap
  containers:
    - name: xxx
      volumeMounts:
        - name: logback-configmap-volume
          mountPath: /config
      env:
        - name: logging.config
          value: /config/logback-spring.xml
```

Please tell me if it's possible not to use volumes to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 <springProperty name="appName" source="spring.application.name" scope="context"/>
```

try this -

```
 <springProperty name="appName" source="${bundle:application:spring.application.name}" scope="context"/>
```

and if you have to read something from the configmap as a property, you can try this -

```
 <springProperty name="logLevel" source="${env:LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}" scope="context"/>
```

I have provided a default value if the property is not present in config-map.

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't helpful - the error stays the same. Btw, I thought `bundle:application` is log4j2-specific, isn't it?